# Class from Schema

Tags: c#, xml, class

I have used the xsd.exe tool to generate a class from a schema, when de-serialising a valid XML document then I get exceptions.

Example xml is here : http://codepaste.net/wq22hy

Class definition is here : http://codepaste.net/bdy598

The problem is at the  element, in that the class definition does not seem to handle the recursive nature of this element.

Within a  element, its children can be either another  or a  element - the generated class does not seem to cater for this.

Any help on how I can fix this.

Comment: I tried adding 

[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("SegGroup", typeof(SegGroup))]

within the SegGroup class in order to achieve the recursion, but this caused an error in the definition of the XmlSerializer class.


Error was :
Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'P1.Segment' to 'P1.SegGroup'
error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'P1.SegGroup' to 'P1.Segment'

Comment: How are you doing your de-serializing? I took the xml and the class definition and was able to de-serialize without an exception.  The object de-serialized appears valid.

Comment: Thanks for looking Mark. I dont have the code with me at the moment. My code did do the de-serialise without an exception, it was just that the de-serialisation was incomplete.

If you look at the example XML then the first <SegGroup> element was in the object along with it's attributes, but none of its child elements from the XML were there.

Comment: For info, it's not the XML de-serialise function that is the problem, its the class file generated by the xsd.exe utility. The SegGroup class can only contain Segment classes, whereas it should be able to contain both "Segment" and "SegGroup" classes ( i.e. it's recursive).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops - a bit of a schoolboy error. The class used for the de-serialisation was generated from the wrong schema file. The schema file used did not have the recursion within it and hence it was not instantiated within the generated class.